# How to download reports from NDepend

Tags: ndepend

Is it possible to download the report generated by NDepend? or is there any similar tool using which I can download the report that is generated?

Also does NDepend have support for C++ or Objective-C?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NDepend builds a .html report named `NDependReport.html`, with resources file in a directory named `NDependReportFiles`. There shouldn't be any problem downloading such report, like for example the sample reports we uploaded on our product website:  http://www.ndepend.com/sample-reports/